# VbScript equivalent to PHP's fmod() function

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Converting a PHP script to VBSCRIPT I found the use of fmod() PHP function. I searched for an equivalent in VbScript, but couldn't find any. Is there an equivalent function in VbScript to PHP's fmod() function?

Comment: Why tagged `asp-classic`?

Comment: @JosefZ Because the OP is using VBScript in the context of Classic ASP.

Comment: Exactly as @Lankymart stated. The programming language used is Classic Asp with VbScript.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found out that there isn't, so searching for the calculation I ended up with a custom made vbScript function, as seen below:

```
Function fmod(x,y)
    Dim z
    If y > 0 Then 
        z = Fix( x / y)
    Else  
        z = 1
    End If
    fmod = x - z * y
End Function
```

Comment: Accordig to [PHP Function Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php): `fmod(x,y)` returns the floating point remainder of dividing the dividend (`x`) by the divisor (`y`). The remainder (`r`) is defined as: `x = i * y + r`, for some integer `i`. If `y` is non-zero, `r` has the same sign as `x` and a magnitude less than the magnitude of `y`. So you should use `z = Fix(x/y)` instead of `z = Int(x/y)` and (_last but not least_) pay an attention to `y = 0` case.

Comment: OK @JosefZ, good point on the use of Int and Fix, which I figured out the difference [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4dseb50(v=vs.84).aspx). Also I never thought of the possibility of y = 0 because in my use y is a fixed positive number. How would you handle the zero possibility?

Comment: Instead of `z = Fix(x/y)` use  `z=1 : If Not ( y = 0) Then z = Fix( x / y)`. Here you can see two commands separated with a colon (`:`) on one line. Although this is valid syntax in VBScript, according to [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176989.aspx) "_However, if you want the advice of the Scripting Guys (and who doesn’t?), we would advise you_ never _to use this type of notation. It makes your scripts hard to read, and is just plain ugly. If you do script like this, well, just don’t tell anyone you learned your scripting technique from us_".